# Android app cannot install

Tags: java, android, generics, dex

While developing an app in AIDE for Android I have come across this error. The app would compile successfully but wouldn't install, reporting this error:

> Could not run the App directly as root. Consider disabling direct running in the settings.
>
> WARNING: linker: app_process has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
>   pkg: /storage/sdcard/AppProjects/MyProgram/bin/MyProgram.apk
>    Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
>   exit with 0

I researched what could cause this and mainly came across reasons like "certificate error, try resigning the package" and "setting a permission twice in the manifest" and other stuff, none of which have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem resides. It was in some code which looked very much like this:

```
public class Builder<T extends Base> {
    private final List<Def1> subDefs1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Def2> subDefs2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public Builder<T> add(final Collection<Def1> ds) {
        subDefs1.addAll(ds);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder<T> add(final Collection<Def2> ds) {
        subDefs2.addAll(ds);
        return this;
    }
}

interface Base {}

final class Def1 implements Base {}

final class Def2 implements Base {}
```

I had these `add` methods, which both take a `Collection` of some kind. The problem must be something to do with Java's lacklustre generics and the dexing process, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem: Java thinks you define two methods with the same signature.

Java method signature definition: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

> method declarations have six components, in order:
>
> 1.Modifiers—such as public, private, and others you will learn about later.
>
> 2.The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.
>
> 3.The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as well, but the convention is a little different.
>
> 4.The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses, ().
> If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.
>
> 5. An exception list—to be discussed later.
> 6. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

As you can see above, the specification of generic classes is NOT part of the java method signature. Therefore java detects two add-methods with the same signature.

Comment: This is correct, but why doesn't the compiler detect this issue? As I mentioned, it compiled successfully but didn't install.